# How and where can I can iphone style system button picture?

Tags: iphone, image, button

I would like to make some iPhone system style button, like camera, flash, deveice button in uiimagepickercontroller, where can I can those button picture?
Thank!

Comment: Are you asking where can you download the iPhone icon set?

Comment: Yes, like camera, flash, and rear/Front camera switch button icon

Comment: I have google it for half day, nothing to find.

Comment: @rohou: check this (4 th link)  http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sugexp=cish&gs_nf=1&cp=9&gs_id=4w&xhr=t&q=iphone+icons&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=iphone+ic&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=f&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=1&biw=1608&bih=793&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&cad=b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export images from UIKit : https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Probably you will find necessary icons/images.

Comment: thanks, Guntis, your answer is very helpful.and powerful tool

Answer (score 0):

If u looking for icons means check this website

http://speckyboy.com/2008/07/18/35-free-icon-sets-for-your-iphone-pimp-it-up/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out the popular [glyphish](http://glyphish.com/) set.